# Is it possible in Android to create a view that overlaps the actionbar?

Tags: android

I have created a menu out of a tablelayout. When activated, the menu will animate over the background view, until it covers the whole window.

I would like for this menu to also overlap the actionbar, when the menu is visible. My question is, is it possible to have a view overlap the action bar container? If so, how might I achieve this?

Comment: what is the "title bar" do you mean status bar?

Comment: I am referring to the window's titlebar

Comment: So, just to be perfectly clear, *not* the ActionBar, right? A pre-holo titlebar?

Comment: @Geobits - you are correct, I am not referring to the actionbar

Comment: @Geobits, on hierarchyviewer inspection my last comment was incorrect. I am in fact referring to the action bar container.

Comment: Can you adapt [this answer](http://46424.com/question/255829#.USU9KTWx3nY) to suit your needs?